# CSS, or html or JavaScript to Page table based on columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want CSS or html to break the columns in a new page lets say after 5th column or any column I want.

I want a table in three pages with page-1 having col-1 to col-5, page-2 with col-6 to col-10 and page-3 with col-11 to col-15

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead style="color:#ceb03d">
    <tr>
      <th id="column_1">column1</th>
      <th id="column_2">column2</th>
      <th id="column_3">column3</th>
      <th id="column_4">column4</th>
      <th id="column_5">column5</th>
      <th id="column_6">column6</th>
      <th id="column_7">column7</th>
      <th id="column_8">column8</th>
      <th id="column_9">column9</th>
      <th id="column_10">column10</th>
      <th id="column_11">column11</th>
      <th id="column_12">column12</th>
      <th id="column_13">column13</th>
      <th id="column_14">column14</th>
      <th id="column_15">column15</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in model.items"> //The table contains several rows.
      <td>result1</td>
      <td>result2</td>
      <td>result3</td>
      <td>result4</td>
      <td>result5</td>
      <td>result6</td>
      <td>result7</td>
      <td>result8</td>
      <td>result9</td>
      <td>result10</td>
      <td>result11</td>
      <td>result12</td>
      <td>result13</td>
      <td>result14</td>
      <td>result15</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: pure html / css cannot (cleanly) solve this problem without repeating the content of the table. You'd need to use some javascript to break the table DOM up. Or you are better off generating n tables in the backend code (wherever the data is coming from)

Comment: as I know it is not possible to achieve this using only CSS or HTML. The layout of content on a page is controlled by the browser, and there is no way to tell the browser to split a table into separate pages based on a specific number of columns.

Comment: @Rory How can I do it using a JS?

Comment: @Rory I guess it is possible using media css I just do not know how.